# Conflict detection/resolution in subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization

So I'm building (undirected) graphs from a dataset... I can walk the path of the graph and grab all the nodes, no problem.

I've now got to incorporate "manual overrides" whereby nodes can be forcibly added to the graph, or removed into its own subgraph. (edit: note that "manual break" edges are indicative that its nodes should be in separate subgraphs, so if the dataset includes "manual break 3-4" that implies that nodes 3 and 4 should end up in entirely separate subgraphs; no connecting paths)

Challenge I'm having is when the calculated/walked datapoints interfere with manual overrides, and where/how to break the graph into subgraphs.

Goals during subgraphing:

- break the least number of calculated edges as necessary to observe the manual overrides
- while maintaining the fewest subgraphs as possible (and if the choices is otherwise equal, I'll figure out any remaining ranking criteria)... which is to say that if there is a choice to break a graph into two vs three subgraphs, two is fewer than three.

This example should provide a reasonable demonstration of the issue:
[image]

Visually, I can see that the edge between nodes 1 and 4 can be removed, at which point I'm left with two subgraphs, 1-2-3-7 and 4-5-6.

But I can't for the life of me, figure out a set of rules for reaching that determination.

My dataset includes:

| node | node | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Manual Combine |
| 1 | 4 | Calculated |
| 1 | 7 | Calculated |
| 2 | 3 | Calculated |
| 3 | 4 | Manual Break |
| 3 | 6 | Manual Break |
| 4 | 5 | Calculated |
| 4 | 7 | Manual Break |
| 5 | 6 | Calculated |
| 6 | 7 | Manual Break |

(technically it'll also have the inverse, but the graph is not directional so shouldn't be significant to this post)

---

Edits:

so far we've got two working approaches

- comprehensive approach : step 1, build calculated graph; superimpose manual overrides. step 2, in a loop, calculate shortest path for all manual break overrides (3-4, 3-6, 4-7, 6-7) and identify the most frequent used pathway (1-4 by identifying 3-2-1-4, 3-2-1-4-5-6, 4-1-7, and 6-5-4-1-7, then breaking into each pathway, calculating the max count; ensure that 1-4 and 4-1 are considered equal since this is nondirected graph). Thought here is to find any paths that allow known non-match nodes to exist in the same graph, look for the most used pathway, and break it until there are no paths between known non-matching nodes.
- find any single node that connects nonmatching nodes (so in this example node 1 would be a candidate for connecting to both 4 and 7 which cannot share the same subgraph); use a ranking to remove all but one. This is easier to rationalize, since it's known that 1 can't coexist, but doesn't do anything for longer paths.

thought at the moment is to take a quick pass using the second approach, since it's very fast (closer to O(N) performance), then the first approach to find any other corrections.

in theory they both hit the goals : break least number of connections - in approach 2 it's easy because we know only one can survive; for approach 1 it seems likely since it's focusing on the most heavily used pathway... in terms of minimizing subgraphs, I have no way to know/prove whether either approach will maximize the goal or not.

---

here's an example (unsure if i'm helping or not at this point)

[image]

let's say that i'm allowing calculated lookups to find "related animals", which I want to use for making broader classifications; in this case Canine vs Feline.

The calculation determined the black edges (maybe based on animals with similar colors/shapes/sizes/appendages/etc), and possibly some red edges... the red edges, being "I manually said they're different" (because at some point, a person looked at this classification, and determined that cats and foxes are too different, and defined the Manual Break dataset), need to be preserved after subgraphing (example, fox and dog are close enough so sure, but fox and cat are not the same).

so...

G` = (C + MC) - MB

but also ensuring that G` or subgraphs (G``?) do not contain both nodes in the set of MB edges

Comment: To be honest, it's not clear at all. I will try to formulate what I understand. From the very beginning we are given a graph. We can add an edge or remove an existing edge by moving along a path of the graph. The goal is that the resulting graph has exactly two connected components (or the smallest possible one). Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: @kabenyuk so the first iteration of the graph is built purely by calculation... maybe it doesn't have the 1-2 edge, and has edges 3-4, 3-6, 4-7, 6-7... the second step is to impose the manual edges (add 1-2, remove 3-4, 3-6, 4-7, 6-7), and finally the step is to "remove edges as necessary to ensure the manual break nodes end up in separate subgraphs... that last step is the part that i'm trying to figure out.

edit: for clarity I edited the post to indicate that "manual break = separate subgraph"

Comment: @kabenyuk - so as mentioned in the post, the goal is to identify that the edge between nodes 1 and 4 should be removed, thus satisfying the manual requirements (manual break / manual combine), as well as the other goals to minimize connections broken, minimize subgraph count, etc).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand you at all.
What do you mean "I'm building graphs from a dataset" or "separate subgraphs" or "manual overrides"?

This seems to be a very interesting topic, but it's a pity that you use terms that don't allow me to understand you.

Comment: @kabenyuk - happy to help provide clarification. I too find this interesting, and I too find myself lacking the proper terms and using "whatever seems best"

Comment: @kabenyuk - an automated process for entity matching reads data and calculates an initial graph. What we've found, is that entity matching with graphs works really well in some ways, but can make really "long" graphs with lots of transitive connections (using geometry terms), which we call "inferred" since the edge 2-7 is not calculated but inferred by the fact that they're in the same graph.

Comment: @kabenyuk - so while the calculations are working well, they occasionally need to be manually overridden to prevent "really long" graphs with lots of "inferred" edges, since we know that there end up being too many transformations in data and that the long ends don't belong in the same graph... thus the "manually combine" and "manually break" datasets... those superimpose atop the calculated dataset... but that dataset is either very large (every combination of nodes) at which point calculating is pointless, or the dataset can be focused on "just" the connections that need to be kept apart

Comment: @kabenyuk - so we're focusing on the smaller / targetted dataset; we know that future datapoints may arrive so it NEEDS to be calculated vs manual override of every combination... just need to figure out the best way to split a single graph into multiple subgraphs given the constraints (manual combine/break records).

Comment: If I try to rephrase your problem with graph terminology, we have 3 sets of edges, MB, MC and C (Manual Break, Manual Combine and Calculated). Let $G' = G - MB$ be the graph without manual break edges. We want to find a set of edges $S \subset C$ such that for every edge $uv$ in $MB$, for every path in $G'$ from $u$ to $v$, the path have at least one edge in $S$. We want $S$ as small as possible and to have the least number of connected components in $G'-S$. If I understood it correctly, I'm afraid that we have NP-hard problems at hand...

Comment: Is there some structure in your problem, for example, is the Manual Break subgraph always a complete bipartite graph, as in your example (in which case you get a polynomial algorithm) ?

Comment: @caduk - thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ok that's much clearer now, thanks for explanation. Still a bunch of question : Is there always two different class in your classification, or could there be more ? Could there be indications that a specific node belongs to a specific class, rather than indicating a pair of different objects ? Can we make use of transitivity relation ? (For example, in the case of two classes, if $a$ is different from $b$ and $b$ is different from $c$, then $a$ is in the same class of $c$ ? This type of reasoning can also be applied with more classes...)

Comment: @caduk : so we don't know how many subgraphs may exist; in theory the calculation should be "right" and is REALLY good, but for the <1% scenarios we want some control... the calculation side is also being tweaked (one rule seems a tad over-reaching and the analyst is digging through the numbers to adjust it)... in terms of indications, transitive relations (I'd used the term 'inferred') are actually our biggest warning right now, they tend to indicate that one or very few nodes are combining two subgraphs.

Comment: What if in your example, Dog and Wolf are feline, your algorithm would still remove the edge Dog-Cat, but now, this is worrying...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what calculated edges are. If I understand correctly, a Manual Combine is an assertion that two nodes belong to the same class, and a manual break is an assertion that two nodes belong to 2 distinct classes. But I don't understand what information brings a calculated edge (or the absence of a calculated edge)

Comment: @caduk the process starts with a single node input, then "explores" the rest of raw data for "similar looking" nodes... uses various layers of calculation to decide whether those "similar looking" nodes get an edge connecting from the input... this is repeated as long as those nodes are assigned edges connecting them to the initial node (via the graph, whether direct or transitive)... that builds the initial "calculated" graph... then superimpose the MC and MBs

Answer (score 1):

Your greedy approach will not give optimal solutions in the general case. For example, take the star graph $S_4$ ($1$ is the internal node, 2,3,4,5 are the leaves). If we add $13,14,15,23,24,25$ as Manual Break edges, then the most frequent used pathway is the edge $12$, but the optimum is to remove $13,14,15$. If you are worried that Manual Combine edges match Calculated Break edges, you can replace edges by paths of length 2.

We have 3 sets of edges, $MB$, $MC$ and $C$ (Manual Break, Manual Combine and Calculated). Let $G′=G−MB$ be the graph without Manual Break edges.

If we consider the minimization of the broken  Calculated edges, the problem is equivalent to the minimal multicut in $G'$ (we want to find a cut which separate each extremities of each Manual Combine edge). As it is NP-hard, there is probably no polynomial algorithm.
See Marie-Christine, Costa & Létocart, Lucas & Roupin, Frédéric. (2005). [Minimal multicut and maximal integer multiflow: A survey](https://www-lipn.univ-paris13.fr/%7Eletocart/SURVEY.pdf). European Journal of Operational Research. 162. 55-69. 10.1016/j.ejor.2003.10.037.

If we consider the minimization of the number of classes (connected components), it is also NP-Hard, by reducing graph coloring to it. If we have all edges calculated, then the minimal number of classes is the chromatic index of the graph composed only of the Manual Break edges. If not all edges are calculated, this is no longer true. For example, the graph composed of Calculated edges $12$, $13$, $14$, $15$ and of Manual Break edges $23$, $45$ have at least 2 classes, but the chromatic index of the graph on Manual Break edges is 3.

The minimization of the broken Calculated edges does not imply the minimization of the number of connected components. For example, if we take the graph where the Manual Break edges are $12$ and $34$, and the Calculated edges are $13$, $24$ and three disjoint paths from $1$ to $4$. Then to minimize the number of broken Calculated edges, we need to remove $13$ and $24$, which leaves 3 connected components. If we cut three edges to disconnect the three disjoint paths, then we get only 2 connected components.

Comment: just trying to follow your example... you have star S4 with 1 as the internal node... by that i assume that they have edges as 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5... you then remove the "manual break" edges 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5... thus the remaining edges are: 1-2... at that point i have 4 subgraphs, 1-2, 3, 4, and 5... so long as there were no original edges between those nodes that would contradict the "manual break" edges, there's no conflict thus a feasible solution.

Comment: Yeah it's because you fall in the case where you are worried that Manual Breaks match calculated edges. What if you replace edges by paths of length 2 (except 1-2) ? You then have edges 1-2, 1-3-3', ..., 1-5-5', and manual breaks 1-3', ..., 1-5', 2-3', 2-4', 2-5'. Your algorithm will remove 1-2, where it should remove one edge on each path of length 2.